# Why my code snippet always returns/prints the first record data from the list?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the records of users from the grid using the below code from OrangeHRM demo site with demo credentials. However, It always returns/prints the first record values i.e. Admin. Could you tell me where I did wrong?

*URL:* http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/
*User:* Admin
*Password:* admin
*Users Grid data*: Admin > User Management> User page
*Objective*: Read user names data
**Code:**

```
    WebElement element;
    List<WebElement> usersList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr"));  

    for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
        element = usersList.get(i);
        System.out.println(i+":"+element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/a")).getText());

    }
```

I know, we can achieve it by usng xpath "//*[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a". But, I'd like to select checkbox based on the given name and what's my mistake.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the `given name` in your existing code block untill the end? Wouldn't had been better to retrieve it through `"//*[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"`?

Comment: Is it not supposed to print Admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solutions

```
 System.out.println(i+":"+element.findElement(By.xpath("td[2]/a")).getText());
 System.out.println(i+":"+element.findElement(By.xpath("decendent:td[2]/a")).getText()); 
 System.out.println(i+":"+element.findElement(By.xpath(".td[2]/a")).getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it more convenient way like below.

```
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("resultTable"));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        List<WebElement> oddNames = table.findElements(By.className("odd"));
        for(WebElement elem : oddNames){
            System.out.println(elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText());
            String name = elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
            list.add(name);
        }
        List<WebElement> evenNames = table.findElements(By.className("even"));
        for(WebElement elem : evenNames){
            System.out.println(elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText());
            String name = elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
            list.add(name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code you will get list of usernames

```
List<WebElement> _Name=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr")); 
        for(int j=0;j<_Name.size();j++)
        {
        String str="//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[";   System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(str+j+"]/td[2]")).getText());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all `tr` elements and keep them on a WebElement list. Then get the user link element using tagName `a` in the loop. And finally use `getText()` to retrieve each user name.

You can use like below:

```
List<WebElement> usersList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr")); 
    for (WebElement userElem : usersList) {
        String username = userElem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
        System.out.println(username);
    }
```

I think, it is more convenient than other solutions as the solution not using any `tr` `td` index. You know, different browser behaves differently. so index may be changed sometimes for different browser.

Comment: @Jagadeep check my solution. It will be more helpful for you. The answer you accepted, need to write more and more lines of code if the user list is bigger. we can't use such kind of redundant code in our application.